# how do i install jdk-8u31-linux-i586.rpm in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu

please provide steps to install jdk-8u31-linux-i586.rpm in ubuntu.

I tried looking through the existing posts but none of them provide the steps, I have already downloaded the file jdk-8u31-linux-i586.rpm from the oracle site...and its now in my download folder

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFGGEFG

Comment: .rpm is for Redhat Based Distros  Ubuntu is debian based.  Look for a .deb or see if there is something in apt that fulfills your needs. or if you follow the link that @rmuller posted, use the tarball (.tar.gz) version of the installer

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install it via apt-get. If you need any jdk8 try the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

If it failed post the errors here.

Comment: getting the following error  msg:E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Yep, there's probably another instance of apt-get running, you can release lock manually: `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock;  sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock;`